# Each $A\in SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $A^3-\alpha A^2+\alpha A-I_3=0$ with $-1\leq \alpha \leq 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

Let $G=SO(3,\mathbb{R})=\{A\in GL(3,\mathbb{R}):A^TA=I_3, \det(A)=1\}$.

a) Show that for any element $A$ in $G$, there exists a real number $\alpha$ with $-1\leq\alpha\leq 3$ such that $A^3-\alpha A^2+\alpha A-I_3=0$.

b) For which real numbers $\alpha$ with $-1\leq \alpha\leq 3$ does there exist an element $A$ in $G$ whose minimal polynomial is $x^3-\alpha x^2+\alpha x-1$?

**Answer:**

What I know is that since the dimensions of the matrices are three, the characteristic polynomial of each $A$ must be a three dimensional polynomial. Also, since each three dimensional polynomial has at least one real root, every matrix $A$ must have an eigenvector. Moreover, any matrix $A$ in $G$ has the property that sum of the squares of the entries in each row of $A$ must be 1, i.e. $A_{i1}^2+A_{i2}^2+A_{i3}^2=1$. However, I could not relate this knowledge to solve the questions. Any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Start off with this instead:   the dot product of two (column) vectors $x \cdot y $  is the same as either $x^T y$ and $y^T x.$   We normally equate a 1 by 1 matrix with its entry......Now, Suppose we take a (real) unit eigenvector $x$  with real eigenvalue $r.$   Unit means $x \cdot x = 1.$  We also demand $Ax = rx.$   Now, for you:  what is $Ax \cdot Ax \; \; ? $

Comment: Do you know that every member of $SO(3,\mathbb R)$ is a rotation matrix?

Comment: @WillJagy Now I start seeing stuff. Since $A\in G$, $Ax\cdot Ax=1$. Also, since $Ax=rx$, $Ax\cdot Ax=r^2$. Thus, $r=\pm1$. Take $r=1$ and say other roots of the characteristic polynomial are $a+bi$ and $a-bi$. Then we get the polynomial $x^3+(-1-2a)x^2+(a^2+b^2+2a)x-a^2-b^2$. Now if I show $a^2+b^2=1$, I'm partially done but why's that so?

Comment: What is the product of the eigenvalues?

Comment: @WillJagy Ohh now i see. It is the determinant of $A$. Thanks a lot. If you don't mind, I want to gather everything and write as an answer.

Comment: good....................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\in G$. Since $A$ is an $3\times 3$ matrix, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of degree three. Thus, $A$ must have at least one real eigenvector. Suppose $v$ is a unit real eigenvector, say $Av=rv$. Consider the dot product of two vectors, i.e. $v\cdot w=v^Tw$. Observe that

$$Av\cdot Av=(Av)^TAv=v^TA^TAv=v^Tv=1$$

Also,

$$Av\cdot Av=rv\cdot rv=r^2 v^Tv=r^2$$

Thus, $r^2=1$, whence $r=\pm 1$. Say that $a\pm bi$ are the other eigenvalues of $A$. Suppose first that $r=-1$. Then $1=\det A=(-1)(a+bi)(a-bi)$. Hence, $-1=a^2+b^2$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $r=1$ and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is

$$(x-1)(x-(a+bi))(x-(a-bi))=x^3+(-1-2a)x^2+(1+2a)x-1.$$

Say $\alpha=1+2a$. Realize that since $a^2+b^2=1$, $-1\leq \alpha \leq 3$. Moreover, in order for this polynomial to be the minimal polynomial of $A$, the other roots must me nonreal. Hence, $b\neq0$ implies that $-1<\alpha<3$.